# Cordova InAppBrowser show location bar Cordova AngularJS Oauth

Tags: angularjs, cordova, oauth, inappbrowser

Hi I'm using the Cordova InAppBrowser and AngularJS Oauth plugins.

When I press a normal link button like this:

```
<a class="external" ng-href="https://www.website.com/" targe="_blank" >open link</a>
```

In combination with this:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        // open links in native browser (phonegap);
        $(document).on('click', '.external', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

It opens the link in the in app browser. In the InAppBrowser when loading the url it is showing the url location at the bottom. So this is working OK.

When the AngularJS Oauth plugin opens the InAppBrowser and starts to load the login page of Facebook for example it doesn't show the loading url location at the bottom.

I tried to add `"location=yes"` in the Oauth plugin like this, but it is still not showing the url loading bar at the bottom:

```
window.open('https://www.website.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=' + clientId + '&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback&scope=' + appScope.join(",") + '&response_type=code&approval_prompt=force', '_blank', 'location=yes,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes');
```

How can I force to show the loading bar with Oauth in the InAppBrowser ?
The reason I want this is when a login page needs some time to load there is no loading indication and you mind think there is nothing happening.

This is how the Oauth function looks like with location=yes:

```
strava: function(clientId, clientSecret, appScope) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                if(window.cordova) {
                    var cordovaMetadata = cordova.require("cordova/plugin_list").metadata;
                    if(cordovaMetadata.hasOwnProperty("cordova-plugin-inappbrowser") === true || cordovaMetadata.hasOwnProperty("org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser") === true) {
                        var browserRef = window.open('https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=' + clientId + '&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback&scope=' + appScope.join(",") + '&response_type=code&approval_prompt=force', '_blank', 'location=yes,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes');
                        browserRef.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
                            if((event.url).indexOf("http://localhost") === 0) {
                                requestToken = (event.url).split("code=")[1];
                                $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
                                $http({method: "post", url: "https://www.strava.com/oauth/token", data: "client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret + "&code=" + requestToken })
                                .success(function(data) {
                                    deferred.resolve(data);
                                })
                                .error(function(data, status) {
                                    deferred.reject("Problem authenticating");
                                })
                                .finally(function() {
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        browserRef.close();
                                    }, 10);
                                });
                            }
                        });
                        browserRef.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {
                            deferred.reject("The sign in flow was canceled");
                        });
                    } else {
                        deferred.reject("Could not find InAppBrowser plugin");
                    }
                } else {
                    deferred.reject("Cannot authenticate via a web browser");
                }
                return deferred.promise;
            },
```

Comment: can you link the AngularJS Oauth you are using?

Comment: I'm using this one https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth

Comment: on https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth/blob/master/src/oauth.js there are a lot of window.open with location=no, are you sure you changed to yes the one you want? or did you change all of them?

Comment: @jcesarmobile I only use one (strava), and yes I changed it to yes, see my code snipped in my question.

Comment: And how/where are you changing it? Are you sure the device get the changes?

Comment: @jcesarmobile I added my code above to show you the strava function

Comment: Yes, I understood that the first time, but in which file do you edit that? Did you fork the plugin, changed that and installed your fork instead of the original? Or where is the oauth.js you edit?

Comment: @jcesarmobile O sorry, I changed it in the ng-cordova-oauth.js file. I use the file locally in the app.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
My app was loading the oauth plugin twice, once via a separate oauth script I added to my project and once via the ngCordova library. The ngCordova script was overruling the oauth script I added  so that's why the location=yes was not working.

I removed the separate oauth script and changed location=no to yes in the ngCordova oauth script.